# What are recommended practices to verify the "type" of function's input arguments in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices in error reporting (Mathematica)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560116/best-practices-in-error-reporting-mathematica)

Assume that I have a function

```
func[xNumber_,str_,listOfReals_]:=Module[{},
....
]
```

and I want to test that the user gave input expressions of the correct type. I know I can do something like `xNumber_?NumberQ` but then I don't seem to find how to generate some informative error message. Therefore, currently, in the the module's code I inserts `If`'s where I test the arguments' types and in case test fails I print some message and return `False`.

What should be considered smarter/more canonical/better practices to achieve this?

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of [Best practices in error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6560116/421225), for which [Leonid](http://stackoverflow.com/users/565518/) gave the [canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6563886/421225).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built-in function `Message` is what you need. The following example is from the documentation.

First define a function that issues an error message and returns unevaluated upon error

```
 rsqrt[x_] /; If[TrueQ[x >= 0], True, Message[rsqrt::nnarg, x]; False] := Sqrt[x]
```

Next, define the message

```
 rsqrt::nnarg = "The argument `1` is not greater than or equal to zero.";
```

With correct input the function evaluates as defined

```
 rsqrt[2.25]
```

returns `1.5`. But, with incorrect input, you get

```
 In[4]:= rsqrt[-2.25]

 During evaluation of In[4]:= rsqrt::nnarg: The argument -2.25 is not greater than or equal to

 zero.

 Out[4]= rsqrt[-2.25]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use Assert. see ?Assert for examples.

One nice thing about Assert is that you can turn Asserts off, and then this will not affect code performance at the end.  i.e. when done debugging and testing your code.

You can also use Assert to generate messages for those function calls that do not pass the correct type, like this:

```
foo[x_?(NumericQ[#] &)] := x^2
foo[x_] := Assert[NumericQ[x]]


On[Assert]
foo[3]
===>9

foo["a"]
===>Assert::asrtf: Assertion NumericQ[a] failed. >>
```

Comment: You can switch messages off and on individually, e.g. `Off[rsqrt::nnarg]`, whereas Asserts are are switched off and on collectively, e.g. `Off[Assert]`.